# Matlab plot(x,ans)?

Tags: matlab

hello everyone I have a code completed that does everything I want it to do I am just stuck on displaying my output.  I don't have that much experience with functions and I am currently stuck on how to plot my information. My code written is:

```
function x = Tridiag(e,f,g,r) 
% Tridiag: Tridiagonal equation solver banded system 
%   x = Tridiag(e,f,g,r): Tridiagonal system solver. 
clc;clear;
% input: 
    D = 2;
    U =1;
    L = 0.2;
    c0 = 80;
    c10 = 10;
    dx = 1;
    n=9;
  e = ones(n,1)*(-2.5);
  f = ones(n,1)*(4.2);
  g = ones(n,1)*(-1.5);
   r = [200;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;15];
% output: 
%   x = solution vector  
% forward elimination 
for k = 2:n
    factor = e(k)/f(k-1);
    f(k) = f(k) - factor*g(k-1); 
    r(k) = r(k) - factor*r(k-1); 
end
% back substitution 
x(n) = r(n)/f(n); 
for k = n-1:-1:1 
    x(k) = (r(k)-g(k)*x(k+1))/f(k);
end
end
```

currently when you run the function it displays the output as ans= 68.641, 58.87.... and so on. I would like to plot my information in the following manner:

```
x = 0.1:1:10
plot(x,ans)
```

I am running into the issue of x = 0.1:1:10 overwritting the value of my function and matlab doesnt understand "ans". I tried to make ans using a variable like `c = Tridiag(e,f,g,r); plot (x,c)` but this doesnt work.  Any help would be greatly appeciated

Comment: Just store the return value of the function: `outval = Tridiag(...); plot(x,outval);`.

Comment: `% back substitution 
x(n) = r(n)/f(n); 
for k = n-1:-1:1 
    x(k) = (r(k)-g(k)*x(k+1))/f(k);
end
outval = Tridiag(e,f,g,r);
plot(x,outval)
end` I get the error :Undefined function 'Tridiag' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: You need to call the function from outside the function...either from another function or from the MATLAB command line. Where were you writing that `plot`...?

Comment: I added the plot at the end of the function to try to get it to plot the information once the function is complete.

Comment: There are a few issues. i feel like they are easy to handle, but you have to give us some information. why are `e,f,g,r` variables when they get defined in the function? do you want to be able to call this with different calus of `e,f,g,r`. when you want to plot those values where do you want them to be on x  and y axis and how many do you want? your command `x = 0.1:1:10` creates 0.1;1.1;....9.1 but i feel like you want 1;1.1;1.2;1.3...10 right? an how does your Tridiag realte to the x value??

Comment: @jake that is bad programming practice. Dont make the function plot, make the fucntion compute the values, and the plot outside.

Comment: "_this doesnt work_" is never very informative without the actual error message. Did you forget to redefine `x` between the call to the function and the call to `plot`?. Try `c = Tridiag(e,f,g,r); x = 0.1:1:10; plot (x,c)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues and a few different solutions:

- The length of you vector `ans` and `x` whatever they are is not the same.
- You are passing variable to the function but not using them (you are even clearing them at the start of the function).

I will assume that `x` should be the the length of `ans` which is `n=9`. You should scale as you see fit.

---

You can run everything in script, instead of a function.

```
clc; clear;

D = 2;
U =1;
L = 0.2;
c0 = 80;
c10 = 10;
dx = 1;
n=9;
e = ones(n,1)*(-2.5);
f = ones(n,1)*(4.2);
g = ones(n,1)*(-1.5);
r = [200;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;15];
% output:
%   x = solution vector
% forward elimination
for k = 2:n
    factor = e(k)/f(k-1);
    f(k) = f(k) - factor*g(k-1);
    r(k) = r(k) - factor*r(k-1);
end
% back substitution
y(n) = r(n)/f(n);
for k = n-1:-1:1
    y(k) = (r(k)-g(k)*y(k+1))/f(k);
end

x = 1:1:n;
plot(x,y)
```

---

Or specify a function:

```
function x = Tridiag(e,f,g,r,n)
% Tridiag: Tridiagonal equation solver banded system
%   x = Tridiag(e,f,g,r): Tridiagonal system solver.
% input:
D = 2;
U =1;
L = 0.2;
c0 = 80;
c10 = 10;
dx = 1;
% output:
%   x = solution vector
% forward elimination
for k = 2:n
    factor = e(k)/f(k-1);
    f(k) = f(k) - factor*g(k-1);
    r(k) = r(k) - factor*r(k-1);
end
% back substitution
x(n) = r(n)/f(n);
for k = n-1:-1:1
    x(k) = (r(k)-g(k)*x(k+1))/f(k);
end
end
```

and call it:

```
n=9;
e = ones(n,1)*(-2.5);
f = ones(n,1)*(4.2);
g = ones(n,1)*(-1.5);
r = [200;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;15];
x = 1:1:n;
plot(x,Tridiag(e,f,g,r,n))
```